# Do I need a closure to make this TweenLite example work as desired?

Tags: actionscript-3, scope, gsap

I seem to recall something about pass-by-reference and the Greensock TweenLite class. It's the only thing I can think of that is causing this bit of code to be not working as I intend:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    addItem();
}



public function addItem():MovieClip {
    var item:MovieClip = getNewItem();

    item.y = item.height / 2;
    var newPosY = _origHeight - _items.length * item.height;

    _items.push(item);
    new TweenLite(item, ITEM_DROP_TIME, { y: newPosY } ); trace(newPosY);

    addChild(item);
}
```

The trace is outputting the values I expect: an incremental sequence where each number is greater than the last (by the height of the item). However, what I see visually is that all the items end up at the same location (as if `newPosY` were the same for all instances of the tween.)

The only thing that comes to mind is that newPosY is being passed by reference, so each instance of the tween is actually referencing the very same value. Am I missing something? Or do I need some kind of closure to isolate the scope of my tween property's value?

EDIT

Suggesting this question be closed as I guess the answer is "No" and the issue was elsewhere in my code. I doubt that any further exposition of the problem would be relevant to others. Thanks to those who responded!

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot replicate the problem. Can you add more context to your question? Nothing from this snippet, prevents the code from working as intended.

Comment: @joncys Thank you, you were right. It took your confirmation that my TweenLite call was correct to force me to look at other parts of my code, and I found that I was over-riding the tween with another tween at a later stage. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I think your TweenLite syntax is wrong. Try:

```
TweenLite.to (item, ITEM_DROP_TIME, { y: newPosY } );
```

Comment: `TweenLite.to` simply returns a `new TweenLite(target, duration, vars)` instance. This cannot be the problem. The real problem must be somewhere out of the scope of the code posted.

Comment: Thanks @James. Both syntaxes work perfectly well. the .to() method is the "old" way it used to work, and is still maintained for compatibility.